# http://localhost:3000/ が開けません。

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

**前提・実現したいこと**

Ruby on rails を用いて新しくアプリを作成するため、 
「http://localhost:3000/」 を開こうとしたところ、 
下記のエラーメッセージが表示されます。 
考えうる理由をご教示頂けないでしょうか？

**発生している問題・エラーメッセージ**

[image: https://gyazo.com/b782667f1dbce40947f3ef98c519575b]

**補足情報(言語/FW/ツール等のバージョンなど)**

・ターミナルの状態 
以前別のアプリを開発していたため、そのターミナル画面にて「exit」を行い、下記のメッセージが表示されました。

＜別アプリのターミナル上のメッセージ＞

```
TOMOAKI-no-MacBook-Pro:photolog TOMOAKI$ exit 
logout 
[プロセスが完了しました]
```

＜現状開発中のターミナル＞ 
① `rails new mysecondapp`
② `./bin/rails s`
上記のコマンドまでは無事に完了しております。

何卒よろしくお願い致します。

---

＜１/２５追記　ログメッセージ＞
[image: https://gyazo.com/725346afa2d0e25d8d29a716bc46f0db]
[image: https://gyazo.com/563eb890d78e8bc8832d72ff3b6077f3]

Comment: ./bin/rails s した後に現れるログメッセージを載せてもらうと何か原因がわかるかもしれません。

Comment: rails を動かしているマシンとアクセスしているマシンは同じですか?
もし異なるのであれば 「rails server -b 0.0.0.0」とタイプして rails を起動してみてください。もし、それで解決したのならその旨をここに報告した方がいいです。(上記のコマンドの意味知らないとちょっぴり危険です)

Comment: ＜１/２５追記　ログメッセージ＞ gyazo.com/725346afa2d0e25d8d29a716bc46f0db gyazo.com/563eb890d78e8bc8832d72ff3b6077f3

Comment: ご回答頂きまして、ありがとうございます。 
上記の通り、ログメッセージを貼り付けましたので、お手数ですが、ご確認頂けますでしょうか？

Comment: ご対応ありがとうございました！！
無事に対応完了しました。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

エラー画面を見る限りおそらく、正常にアプリケーションサーバが起動していない(`./bin/rails s`がうまく動いていない)かと思われます。

まずはお使いのターミナルで、`lsof -i4TCP:3000`と`ps PID`コマンドにて**port:3000番**のプロセスが`rails s`によってlistenされているか確認してみてはどうでしょうか。

e.g. port3000番がアプリケーションサーバによってlistenされている場合

```
$ lsof -i4TCP:3000
COMMAND   PID      USER   FD   TYPE             DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
ruby    1539 fukuiretu   13u  IPv4 0x8666b6ee0e33300d      0t0  TCP localhost:hbci (LISTEN)
$ ps 1539
PID   TT  STAT      TIME COMMAND
1539 s003  S+     0:02.21 /Users/fukuiretu/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/bin/ruby bin/rails s
```

上記コマンドにより、何も標準出力がなければアプリケーションサーバが起動していないということになります。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます！！

「lsof -i4TCP:3000」は何も標準出無し。
「ps 1539」は下記の出力でした。

＜ps 1539の出力＞
TOMOAKI-no-MacBook-Pro:mysecondapp TOMOAKI$ ps PID
ps: illegal option -- P
usage: ps [-AaCcEefhjlMmrSTvwXx] [-O fmt | -o fmt] [-G gid[,gid...]]
          [-u]
          [-p pid[,pid...]] [-t tty[,tty...]] [-U user[,user...]]
       ps [-L]
TOMOAKI-no-MacBook-Pro:mysecondapp TOMOAKI$

Comment: おっしゃる通り、正常にアプリケーションサーバが起動していないと思われますが、どのように対処したら良いでしょうか？

Comment: やはりそうでしたか。@JunichiIto さんが上で仰られている通り、

> ./bin/rails s した後に現れるログメッセージを載せてもらうと何か原因がわかるかもしれません。

ログメッセージがないことには原因が分かりかねますので、まずはログメッセージを載せていただければと思います。

あとは、Railsチュートリアルの http://railstutorial.jp/chapters/beginning?version=4.2#sec-the_hello_application この辺りを読むと何かヒントがあるかもしれません。

Comment: ＜１/２５追記　ログメッセージ＞
https://gyazo.com/725346afa2d0e25d8d29a716bc46f0db
https://gyazo.com/563eb890d78e8bc8832d72ff3b6077f3

Comment: ありがとうございます。
上記の通り、ログメッセージを貼り付けましたので、お手数ですが、ご確認頂けますでしょうか？

Comment: `routes.rb`にて構文エラーが出ているようです。**unexpected keyword_end** とあるので、`end`の閉じ忘れなどがないか再度確認すると良いと思います。

Comment: ご対応ありがとうございました！！
無事に対応完了しました。

Answer (score 0):

ログメッセージの画像を確認しました。（ちなみに画像よりもテキストでコピペしてもらった方がベターです）

原因はログに書いてあります。
このログを見て「あ、ここが原因かな」という予想が付かないと、今後も頻繁に行き詰まると思います。
まずはログの読み方をしっかり勉強しましょう。

今回はログのこの部分に注目してください。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

`～/config/routes.rb:60` とあるので、routes.rbの60行目付近に問題があることがうかがえます。

またその後ろに `syntax error, unexpected keyword end` と書いてあります。
これは日本語にすると「構文エラー。予期しない end キーワードあり」という意味です。

おそらくroutes.rbを編集するときにミスをして、doとendがきれいにマッチしなくなったのでは？と予想します。

たとえばこんな感じです。

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root                'static_pages#home'
  resources :users do
    member do
      get :following, :followers
  end
end
```

routes.rbをしっかり見直せば修正できると思いますが、もしどうしても解決しない場合はroutes.rbのコード全体を追記してください。（ただし画像ではなくテキストで）

Comment: ご対応ありがとうございました！！
無事に対応完了しました。

Comment: 解決したのであれば良かったです。こちらを参考にして回答の承認をお願いします。 http://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers 承認してもらうと福田さんの信用度もアップしますので。（こちらも参考にどうぞ => http://blog.jnito.com/entry/2015/10/04/073825 ）

Comment: @Junichi Ito さん
ご丁寧にありがとうございます！